# Column width in html table is wrongly expanded

Tags: html, css

The width of first column in the html file(see [Book1.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p67dbs5jzrjnlrw/Book1.zip?dl=0)) is defined in `col` tag of `colgroup`, also it is defined in the first row in `tr` tag. But the width of first column expands a lot comparing the desired `145px`. see srceenshot:
[image: column width expands a lot]

Why the column width expands so much? And how to fix the column width to the desired '145px'?

Comment: Maybe some CSS override the width

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), provide a proper [mre] of the issue instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Hkachhia The source file Book1.zip is attached in the post, open the html in Chrome, Chrome Developer tools shows that the setting width is taking effect.